# Cattle counter based on events log

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

Given some event data that only consists of an **id** and a type of **event** (entry/exit) I'd like to compute a third column which could keep track of the current state of things (**count**), basically stating how many animals are present at any given time.

Example:

```
id   event
--------------
1    entry
2    entry
3    entry
4    entry
5    exit
6    exit
7    entry
```

I'd need an output similar to this (considering it starts empty)

```
    id    event        count
-----------------------------
    1     entry        1
    2     entry        2
    3     entry        3
    4     entry        4
    5     exit         3
    6     exit         2
    7     entry        3
```

Where **count** holds keeps track of the actual number of animals after that event has been processed.

I've been trying to take some windowed approach, but after a couple of hours I just can't seem to nail it (I'm quite new to this yet).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding of your requirements: For each event calculate a number based on the prior events (including the current one).
That is indeed possible by using a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
SELECT id, event, addend, SUM(addend) OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) AS count FROM (
  SELECT id, event, 
  CASE WHEN event = 'entry' THEN 1 WHEN event = 'exit' THEN -1 ELSE 0 END AS addend 
  FROM events
) AS events_with_addend
```

The type of `event` does not contain any information we can use in the aggregate sum, so we have to provide it (in the inner query).

Instead it is preferred to create a separate table `event_types` containing the name of the event as well as the change applied to count by it, then referencing `event_types`from `events` (look up *database normalization*) and losing the inner query.

The actual window function then just sums up the addends of each row until (including) the current one (the *window frame*).

It is very possible this approach might lead to performance problems depending on the (growing) count of rows. If it does, have a look into [materialized views](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rules-materializedviews.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I've been trying to achieve.